# Need to select multiple values as default dynamically in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In a prameter need to select multiple values as default dynamically in jenkins. Because need to run a scheduler on which multiple values should be selected as default. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) to select multiple valued for a variable.

After installing the plugin, in your project configuration page select `This Project is Parameterized` option and then from the drop-down choose `Extended Choice Parameter`.

[image]

Then add a name for your parameter and choose the parameter type as `Multi Select`. Then under `Choose Source for Value` section choose from where you want to take the vales for your parameter and save your job. In the following image I am providing the value in the job itself. You can choose alternate methods.

[image]

Now when you build your project you can select multiple values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, by this we need to select multiple values manually, but according to my use case need to select last 3 values automatically for scheduler.

Comment: I need a little bit more information. Do you have multiple variable in your scheduler? Do you want to provide input while running the job for those variables?

Comment: Yes correct, I have use case like, i have a variable for that i need to select multiple variable (Ex: a,b,c). I have achieved selecting multiple variable by Active choice parameter plugin during triggering manually. But while running cron job or scheduler, I dont know how to select mutliple variable as default(may be last 3 variable need to selected automatically during scheduler or cronjob).

Comment: Have you tried storing the values in a properties file and reading them from it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use source for default value [image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) instead, using for example a simple checkbox configuration